# How can I download non public Facebook video?

Tags: video, facebook

I want to download a video uploaded by a friend on Facebook for offline access. How can I do that? I tried almost all Chrome extensions on Chrome store and none seems to work. Also, youtube-dl didn't work as expected. Any reliable way to download it?

Comment: `youtube-dl` will still work, it just needs the right cookie values to be able to access the video. Use your browser's dev tools to determine the cookie header and add it to the youtube-dl command with the `--add-header` option.

Comment: Related: [Bulk download facebook videos](https://superuser.com/q/1151408/87805).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I use [**Facebook video Downloader**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/facebook-video-downloader/amjcoehkcacocffpmhnefgoeanepjfkf/reviews) Chrome extension to download all public/private Facebook videos. You can get it from the Chrome web store.

Comment: Can you expand on that a bit? How does this solve the problem. How do you use it? This may help: [Best practices for recommending a web app or other tool](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/4059)

Answer (score 22):

[`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) utility will work just fine, it just need your user credentials to be able to access the page.  Like most sites, Facebook uses cookies for this.  If you copy your cookies from your browser when you're logged in and add them to the youtube-dl command like via the `--add-header` option, youtube-dl will be able to access the video and download it.

Here's one way to do it in Chrome:

1. In your web browser, login to Facebook as normal
2. Open Chrome Developer Tools
3. Reload the page
4. In Developer Tools, switch to the **Network** tab and scroll up to the first request
5. Right click the first request and select **Copy as cURL**
6. Paste the cURL command line into a text editor and look for the cookie header information.  You're looking for the part directly that looks like `-H 'cookie: <...>'`.  Copy everything within the quotes.
7. From a terminal, run `youtube-dl`, adding the cookie information using `--add-header` :

   ```
    youtube-dl "<url-of-facebook-video>" --add-header '<cookie-header-from-curl>'
   ```

youtube-dl will now be able to access the page and retrieve the video.

Comment: Does this still work? It does with public videos, but not private ones.
With youtube-dl 2020.11.01.1 all I get is `Cannot parse data`.
Precisely which request should I copy the cookie from? What does that cookie look like?

Comment: Working again with version 2020-12-12.

Comment: ended up using, `--cookies` and downloaded the cookies for my fb browser tab using the _cookies.txt_ browser ext.

Comment: I was able to download a non-public video this way.  I used the cookies from the request to the www.facebook.com user page.  I also copied the user-agent header.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the simplest way to download Facebook video that doesn't require visiting another website or installing/downloading any software before hand.

1. Visit the Facebook page that shows the individual video
2. Replace the "**www.**" part of the address in the browser's URL/address
   bar at the top of the browser with "**mbasic.**" then press Return/Enter and that will load the mobile version of the page.
3. Play the video, then "**right click**" the mouse on the video and you
   should have an option to "**Save Video**"
4. Click "**Save Video**"

Comment: This still works, somewhat. Right-click doesn't, but you can get the URL from the inspector. Not sure how to change video resolution though.

Comment: Works in 2020. NICE ONE!! …change subdomain to `touch` then you have to start playing the video first, then right-click and `Open Video In New Tab` … then go to that tab and right-click to `Save Video As…` — no need for youtube-dl or extracting cookie header or going into dev tools.

Comment: For me replacing www with touch just redirects me to the www site again. however, replacing it with `mbasic` does work for me

Comment: thanks for the heads-up!  i will update the answer to feature mbasic

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to install apps from any of the two listed methods below... If you don't prefer installing firefox, then I'd recommed jDownloader.

### METHOD 1: Flashgot addon for Firefox

[image: Flashgot Addon]

I'd recommend FlashGot Add-on for this (Firefox Browser Add-on)

1. Download [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) (Browser)
2. Unzip via setup—the portable version won't change any registry. And you can simple delete the folder once your video is downloaded or once you've finished downloading all the videos.
3. Open Firefox and go to this URL: http://flashgot.net/
4. Install the FlashGot plugin on your Firefox and restart it for the plugin to activate.
5. Once plugin activated, go to your Facebook video page, and start streaming the video.
6. Once streaming, you'll notice a small video icon at the bottom of the page in Firefox.
7. You should click on the icon for a download window to appear, from where you can download the video.
8. Alternatively, once streaming, you can click on *Tools* → *Flashgot* → *Flashgot Media(1)* and download your video.
9. FlashGot is only supported in Firefox, and not in Chrome. FlashGot also supports download managers like Flashget, Free Download Manager, and Download Accelerator. Default Settings would work for these download managers, and no extra setup is required, if they're installed on your PC.

**Screenshots** : FlashGot Method - [Step 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKrw9.png) ] & [Step 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izVUN.jpg)

### METHOD 2: jDownloader

[image: jDownloader]

Also, if you don't prefer installing a browser, you can install [jDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/).

1. jDownloader is an Open Source download manager which lets you download any video/music/file*.* from almost any source. It's GUI is quite good, and you can add your file hosts accounts for free or paid downloads.
2. In your case, you can add your Facebook account to it, and just copy the Facebook video URL to the clipboard.
3. Once copied, the video will automatically be parsed by the jDownloader, and you can download it from there.

**Screenshot** of [Adding Account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ekMq.jpg) for Facebook. jDownloader treats both free and paid accounts as premium.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to [private Facebook downloader](http://getfbstuff.com/facebook-private-video-downloader);
2. Open Facebook video, right click on the page and copy whole source;
3. Paste it in the private Facebook downloader's text box and click download.

Comment: you are just giving the source code of a private page (that may contain sensitive information) to an unknown, untrusted website. do you think it is safe?